# How to import Domain class into Groovy script?

Tags: grails

Is there a way to access domain objects in a groovy script?  I've tried importing them as usual, but I still get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.  I've also tried adding the package to the `depends` list, but that does not help either.

I am invoking the script via `grails MyScript param1 param2`.  If I run it through `grails run-script scripts/MyScript` then I can import fine, but cannot pass params.

I have seen [this question](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/run-script-Can-scripts-take-command-line-arguments-td4629588.html) that mimics my problem exactly, however, the solution does not seem to work for me.

```
import foo.Bar

includeTargets << grailsScript("Init")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsArgParsing")

target(main: "Does Foo") {
    depends(configureProxy, classpath, parseArguments)

    println argsMap

    Bar.get(1)//Throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

How can I import Domain classes and access script parameters in my Groovy script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run your script with run-script not as a normal script

see [run-script documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-script.html)

I don't think run-script suppor command line arguments actually look at [run script source code](https://bitbucket.org/tednaleid/grails-run-script/src/034ed2a74171/scripts/RunScript.groovy)
.

You can rewrite a run-script clone that pass arguments to running script as bean (like it already do for grailsApplication). I think it's not difficult do to.

Or you can use an external properties files included in your config to pass arguments to grails application, and so to running script.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, if I run it with run-script, I cannot access the params.

Comment: When I run grails scripts with `run-script`, I see `No such property: includeTargets for class`. Any idea what is going on here?